# The function $H(x) =(4\pi t)^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}(1+|y|)^m\,dy$ attains its maximum in $x=0.$

Tags: reference-request, integration, parabolic-pde

In this [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272398/1-s2.0-S0022039600X00782/1-s2.0-S0022039696931964/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEDcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDupPydP66TFKIaldCmMZvWQU%2BxQQbKTb0mvVYeQp%2FyAwIhAJ1fQXgupzUfU5Pwk5i9gylGjDqIeq5SQu2Txp%2BGzJ57KrwFCLD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgyuSbB%2B6y9fhO%2BVOekqkAVj7Uj51XmdcLkYxyn18OWriVS5H2VXuQIr9n81YIf%2FMn3A1grh%2FKdE2QDo7WAQswGqDq4Fe2kQhq1wIrhPSukarrA7uGd9BYRMRntj3JWsRwoWw2joPewe%2BuBZFZTv4Oh2PhccrhKrtgDuEbDPM8fIHrV0UKWQ48NILAhHKM7%2F7y6R2maMG%2B%2BkXn0iT4TIYy9V2kT%2FI2xHX%2BSTgCl3lOpTAqxO2CYdfhqn%2FPGgJh4dys9ZK56IxzI4CnKDG7rzbvjxQUXrq4VQj%2BhWqe5WcdzUg2t5lOgr7xZpVA%2BR7Iec9%2FmRUILEKX%2BAgzLitjyXYKKPBiEvp9gEfMTwCRt0J97ADAZC1NyDGi2Jz7SKqgKRSdnD637C%2F9p7xTf7iAAc6WOSVsTRUEuah%2BxbKq8DSrUjbkrSykQJYmjH9zQV0qcjSpY4Vn%2BfKELGQORlMT1%2BPuk2%2FemQzFSN%2BrEaBTIvfaunMTQ%2BIPkFjtInPkPOzjKEDMaXEMIvvfESXJ%2FPBq4jRY%2F%2BbipBeROU2DNPyZuJRJkA5gKr3O5g315aYHCfOrX%2BBCHZAQrEkPalpTvHifY4D7GpCmw5T0D%2FaYcMNyRBwGbO80FEbvEI%2BQNi5b21QDd42QgE9Qa%2BtC1MT9IIALchUXP4nftQSIfdKhegfbbQjudaxZzOR8kxiJ%2FR%2Bq%2B2dUnuetICD%2F58N7zdnuHPxWHcVTJu21yugPMqV0SunyMiopQY5OPgTVr95fdRocuMLdedQu9nrlsg0x2H3vh1MOjLLlQkmKPuKpRhjPcozmxSXFnKb1IjUbh%2Bo60q973QxovnPW8%2FwVdNxa192rXEHrUosyLayoMxBhnCCnx9Wxp7VEPCbpyjYc00BWqUhVd1iO3hVzD6lLKlBjqwAfBvqrE7VqGONtL8irrFHCR5rLcMwCb%2BviVN5lp4ioyuyjSZxf%2FM5v%2Fwi5wDBd5KDklajbvYq3TBOvW5%2BThRnXE%2FWG0zryiRybUWcxtghTbRbGZztc%2BtrJVX3Lm3%2FfoOwvvd4Tg1m8D2OBSUo4uA2Eft5kUpUtJnVwYwFpLUAgUmRXglqn4GVtnE2rDu8UW9DBh0lqM93UNIi0234jsrZTsRys9sdrfXP6Xs6shwIm4y&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230710T235216Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYVJ7ZWBG4%2F20230710%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7690893b774d6cf762a351a7bc004377d18343a0b1e9f41867f1ab970884bf25&hash=fc536f2508881dc4428adc23ae8fd84c793d245e8ffd80d9cde70a0d8ec1bca7&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022039696931964&tid=spdf-4228bc05-51e1-405f-940e-c0b61baaf69d&sid=71fadf265f80e94e2a6b7324384a1f4e2699gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=041459035a0006575102&rr=7e4cb82a8bd300e8&cc=br), Lemma 6, Pinsky proves that $H(x) =(4\pi t)^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\frac{-|x-y|^2}{4t}}(1+|y|)^m \, dy$ attains its maximum in $x=0.$ I didn't understand the proof very well, but I was visually convinced that the result is true. From the figure below at $a=0$ the area under the graph appears to be maximum if x=0. My question is, if considering the function $G(x) =(4\pi t)^{-n/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}}(1+|y|)^m \, dy$ the same result is true? i.e. the square in $|x-y|$ has some importance? the maximum is reached at $x=0$. In that case how to do it? Would the argument be similar to Pinsky's Lemma 6?

[image]

Comment: I think he simply used spherical coordinates and then proved that the inner integral is nonpositive for each r.

Comment: For the (3.2) integral you can try the conversion done here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816246/exponential-integral-on-n-dimensional-unit-sphere, of turning into the dot-product wrt to the standard vector e1. And then maybe the idea from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340255/find-spherical-integral-int-bf-x-1-x-1-e-bf-xt-bf-y-rm-d?rq=1 to deal with the $x_{1}$.

Comment: The claim also follows from the Riesz rearrangement inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_rearrangement_inequality (set $g(x) = e^{-|x|/4t}$, $h(x) = (1+|x|)^{-m}$, and $f = \delta_x$ (or an approximation thereof)).

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you, I was unaware of this wonderful result! I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: @TerryTao, I couldn't understand why the function itself will have a maximum at $0$, due to the Riesz rearrangement inequality, won't the right side have a maximum at $0$?

Comment: Because $g=g^*$, $h=h^*$, and $f^* = \delta_0$, the rearrangement inequality gives $G(x) \leq G(0)$.

Comment: cool, I was thinking that I would have to guarantee by definition that a rearrangement of $g(x)=e^{-|x-y|/4t}$ is $g^{*}(x)=e^{-|y |/4t}$, and it wasn't working. Now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R} $Of course, we have to assume that $t>0$ -- otherwise, $G(x)$ will be either undefined (if $t=0$) or infinite for all $x$ (if $t<0$). Also, in Pinsky's Lemma 6 it is assumed that $m\le0$.

Let us prove the following statement, which contains both Pinsky's Lemma 6 and your conjecture (and much more):

> **Proposition 1:** For $x\in\R^d$, let
> \begin{equation*}
>     G(x):=\int_{\R^d}dy\,g(|x-y|)f(|y|), \tag{1}\label{1}
> \end{equation*}
> where $g$ and $f$ are nonnegative functions defined on $[0,\infty)$ such that
> \begin{equation*}
>     c:=\int_{\R^d}dy\,g(|y|)<\infty \tag{2}\label{2}
> \end{equation*}
> and $g(|y|)$ is log concave in $y$. Then (i) $G(x)$ is nonincreasing in $|x|$ if $f$ is nonincreasing and (ii) $G(x)$ is nondecreasing in $|x|$ if $f$ is nondecreasing.

*Proof:* Let us first prove part (i) of the conclusion of Proposition 1, where $f$ is nonincreasing.
Without loss of generality (wlog), the function $f$ is right continuous. So, for all real $t\ge0$
\begin{equation*}
    f(t)=f(\infty-)+\int_{(t,\infty)}(-df(u))
    =f(\infty-)+\int_{(0,\infty)}(-df(u))\,f_u(t),
\end{equation*}
where $f(\infty-):=\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ and $f_u(t):=1(t<u)$. So, in view of \eqref{1} and \eqref{2},
\begin{equation*}
    G(x):=cf(\infty-)+\int_{(0,\infty)}(-df(u))\,G_u(x),  \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    G_u(x):=\int_{\R^d}dy\,g(|x-y|)f_u(|y|). 
\end{equation*}
Note that $f_u(|y|)$ is log concave in $y$ and hence in $(x,y)$. Also, $g(|x-y|)$ is log concave in $(x,y)$, since $g(|y|)$ is log concave in $y$. So, $g(|x-y|)f_u(|y|)$ is log concave in $(x,y)$. So, by the Prékopa–Leindler inequality (cf. e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9kopa%E2%80%93Leindler_inequality#Log-concave_distributions)), $G_u(x)$ is log concave in $x\in\R^d$. Also, the function $G_u$ is radial: $G_u(x)$ depends on $x$ only through $|x|$. So, $G_u(x)$ is nonincreasing in $|x|$.

Since $f$ is nonincreasing, the Lebesgue--Stieltjes measure $(-df(u))$ is nonnegative. So, in view of \eqref{3}, $G(x)$ is nonincreasing in $|x|$, which proves part (i) of the conclusion of Proposition 1.

Let us now prove part (ii) of the conclusion of Proposition 1, where $f$ is nondecreasing. Replacing $f$ by $\min(M,f)$ for a real $M>0$, letting $M\to\infty$, and recalling the monotone convergence theorem, we see that wlog $f\le M$ for some real $M>0$. Then the function $M-f$ is nonnegative and nonincreasing. So, by \eqref{2} and part (i) of the conclusion of Proposition 1,
\begin{equation}
Mc-G(x)=Mc-\int_{\R^d}dy\,g(|x-y|)f(|y|) \\ 
=   \int_{\R^d}dy\,g(|x-y|)(M-f(|y|))
\end{equation}
is nonincreasing in $|x|$. So, $G(x)$ is nondecreasing in $|x|$.

Proposition 1 is completely proved. $\quad\Box$

Comment: impressive! Thank you very much for the explanation, I did not know this result. Is it from a book? Or did you create?

Comment: @Ilovemath : There are many applications of the Prékopa–Leindler inequality. Here we have one of them. I have not seen this particular application elsewhere in this same form.